# Good way to show messages and redirect in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an angular application. In a controller I want to set a success or error message and then redirect to another route.

This should give you some idea of what I mean.

```
var myControllers= angular.module('myControllers', []);
myControllers.controller('SomeController', ['$scope', '$http', '$location',
    function ($scope, $http, $location) {
        $scope.doSomething = function () {
            $http.get('/api/dosomething').then(function (result) {
                if (result.data == 'true') {
                    $scope.successMessage = 'Yay it worked !!';
                    $location.path('/someotherroute');    
                }
                else {
                    $scope.errorMessage = 'it did not work';
                }
            });
        };
    }
])
```

Does anyone have a nice solution for passing $scope.successMessage to the new controller ?
(i.e. the controller that is associated with '/someotherroute' )

Comment: Typically when you are passing data between controllers, you use a service/factory. You could post the message to the service/factory, and retrieve it from the new controller.

Comment: Use a service and http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/alert directive to generate alert messages

Comment: @suneetha  ref link is broken

Comment: http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/; use alert directive

Comment: Thanks for the comments, using a service to maintain the state looks like the way to go for me.